Issue with TimeMachine drive hosted on TrueNAS - cannot connect to backup drive
I set up Time Machine according to instructions I found online (but didn't bookmark) utilizing account name for child dataset (path suffix %U) which allows multiple machines to use the same Time Machine share.
For the laptop everything is working fine (macOS 13 - Ventura, WiFi connected).
For the Mac mini (macOS 14.4.1 - Sonoma) I can setup the Time Machine drive but when it attempts to backup to it I just get the error message The backup disk is not available. Make sure the backup disk is connected or select a different backup disk and it won't connect. This seems strange as it accepted the credentials and gave no error when choosing the Time Machine network location.
Given I followed the same instructions to setup each system with the same settings applied to the user account in each case the only difference I can see is the OS version. I can connect to the share using smb://user@server in Finder and choosing the parent Time Machine share which then maps me through to the  child dataset. I can create files here that show in the expected area on the server. However, it’s a no-go on the macOS Time Machine backup.
Any hints at where to look? SMB share settings are the same, account settings are the same, dataset settings are the same, I can map and write to the share etc.

This appears to be an issue with Sonoma specifically.  See this similar question; especially the comments.  Also, you may want to file a bug report at Apple Feedback

Is there a goto place for seeing macOS bug lists before updating? QNAP Forums, for example, has pinned firmware version updates where issues get noted. This would have been very handy before updating from Ventura. Not a show-stopper as I can make do with a USB drive, but good to know in advance.
